# Converting JSON strings with escaped Unicode characters to JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON string which contains an escaped Unicode character. The JSON includes this snippet:

`I co-ordinate our Chat Literacy network \u2013 an online group for practitioners of Information Literacy`

The `\u2013` is a long dash.

I'm using

`var theObject = eval ("(" + jsonString + ")");`

to convert the JSON string to a JavaScript object. I need to use a version of SpiderMonkey that doesn't have a direct JSON to Object method in it.

After conversion, the character in question becomes the Unicode control character `\0013` which is an invalid UTF-8 character.

Is there another way I can convert the JSON to an object which will preserve the correct long-dash character? Maybe some other JSON to Object method I can load?

This happens with some other characters also, like curly quotes.

Thanks,

Doug

Comment: Does anyone know if the JSON.parse method in JSON 3 would solve the problem of the escaped Unicode entities? Or if there is a way of avoiding the problem with the eval() method I'm using?

Answer (score 2):

`eval()` is evil. Stay away from it.
Try using JSON 3: http://bestiejs.github.io/json3/

Comment: Ooo, there's JSON**3**? I'm not keeping up :O

Comment: You know Javascript! :D For everything new there's something newer! :D

Comment: By the time you finish reading this somebody is already working on JSON 4 ;)

Comment: Would the JSON.parse method in JSON 3 help with the problem I mentioned involving escaped Unicode entities?